# ID value not passed to different action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my project, there are two controllers namely Home controller and Hotel controller.I have used view model to combine two model classes.Bellow I have Add my controllers.

Home Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(){
        List<ImageData> details = new List<ImageData>();

        var sp_details = (from s in db.service_provider
                          join p in db.pictures on s.SPID equals p.SPID
                          join c in db.cities on s.City_ID equals c.City_ID
                          select new { s.SPID, s.Sp_name, s.Sp_rate, s.service_type, c.Cityname, p.pic }).OrderByDescending(s => s.Sp_rate).Where(p => p.service_type == "Restaurant").Take(3).ToList();

        foreach (var item in sp_details)
        {
            ImageData SpView = new ImageData(); // ViewModel
            SpView.SPID = item.SPID;
            SpView.Sp_name = item.Sp_name;
            SpView.Cityname = item.Cityname;
            SpView.Sp_rate = item.Sp_rate;
            SpView.pic = item.pic;

            details.Add(SpView);
        }
        return View(details);
    }
```

Hotel controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        List<ImageData> details = new List<ImageData>();

        var sp_details = (from s in db.service_provider
                          join p in db.pictures on s.SPID equals p.SPID
                          join c in db.cities on s.City_ID equals c.City_ID
                          where s.SPID == id
                          select new ImageData()
                          {
                              Sp_name = s.Sp_name,
                              Sp_location = s.Sp_location,
                              Cityname = c.Cityname,
                              service_type = s.service_type,
                              Sp_description = s.Sp_description,
                              Sp_rate = s.Sp_rate,
                              Sp_web = s.Sp_web,
                              Cnt_wh = s.Cnt_wh,
                              pic = p.pic
                          });



        if (details == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(sp_details);
    }
```

below is part of Index view.I have passed id value to Details action method in Hotel Controller.

```
 <p class="name">@Html.ActionLink(item.Sp_name, "Details","Hotel", new { id = item.SPID })</p>
```

but value not passed and not display details of Details Action method in Hotel Controller.Since I'm new to mvc 4 I couldn't able to find the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try explicitly including an additional `null` parameter that would represent your `htmlAttributes` parameter and would match [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29) to ensure that your object was properly passed along as route parameters :

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Sp_name, "Details","Hotel", new { id = item.SPID }, null)
```

The `ActionLink()` helper doesn't contain an overload that only accepts the Text, Action, Controller and RouteValues, which you have supplied, so this extra parameter is necessary.

Comment: just wondering, if the OP's Details ActionResult's parameters are already initialized.. `public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)`, wouldn't his routeValue in the ActionLink be pointless? or does OP's routeValue *override* the `int id =0?`

Comment: The `int id = 0` implies a default parameter with a value of 0. So if an `id` value was supplied, it would override it, if not, 0 would still be used.

Comment: ahh so that is an *optional parameter*?